# Problem doing npm run build on AWS server | JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3

I can see that the build folder has been made but get this error message. I dont know wether I should worry or not. I does not happen when i do it on my local machine?
yeah something def go wrong as I only get these 5 file made?
How can i prevent this
Command ran:

```
npm run build
```

icon.ico  logo192.png  logo512.png  manifest.json  robots.txt

```
FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

 1: 0xb09c10 node::Abort() [/usr/bin/node]
 2: 0xa1c193 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/bin/node]
 3: 0xcf8dbe v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/bin/node]
 4: 0xcf9137 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/bin/node]
 5: 0xeb09d5  [/usr/bin/node]
 6: 0xec069d v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/bin/node]
 7: 0xec339e v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/bin/node]
 8: 0xe848da v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/usr/bin/node]
 9: 0x11fd75c v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInOldGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/bin/node]
10: 0x15f2099  [/usr/bin/node]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the same command but tell node to add more memory:

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 <yourscript>
```

The problem is likely that this is set by environment variables, so your machine probably has a different value to the EC2.

Note that you would not be able to increase the allocated memory (8192MB in this example) more than the available memory of the machine. So if you are only running a `.small` then you are inherently not going to be able to match your own powerful machine.

Comment: I just tried export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192" and than tried npm run build and now waiting for it to build.

Comment: Is there a way to check how much memory i need?

Comment: Easiest is to tune it by adding / removing until you and the machine are happy.

Comment: Everytime I try to run npm run build it just crashes so I guess I will have to upgrade

Comment: yeah; just relaunch it with more memory. please can you mark as correct if this has helped you so others can find it too :)

Comment: I tried your command and got this? 'ubuntu@ip-172-31-24-68:~/apps/bachelor-app/client$ node --max-old-space-size=8192 npm run build
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/ubuntu/apps/bachelor-app/client/npm'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
'

Comment: requireStack: []
}

Comment: If you are running this from NPM please update your Q to include what your command is. Try updating your build script to include setting env var instead: `"build": "MAX_OLD_SPACE_SIZE=4096 <previous script>",`

Comment: My command was just npm run build, I upgraded instance to t2.medium now and will just update the script to what you said. Tested the script on local machine and worked fined will now test on ubuntu

Comment: `node --max_old_space_size=512 node_modules/.bin/react-scripts build` This command started the build atleast

Comment: I dont know what fixed it but now it works atleast. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the memory available to Nodejs.

`NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096" npm run build`